# unable to use retofit 2.0 Beta in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

when i am calling the method of my inteface getRepo it shows an error Service methods cannot return void for method Github.getRepo when i run and check the debug it crash in interfac call wher i make the getRepo method

```js
my mainActivity mtehod to call the api is 

 Github api = GitHubService.getService();
         api.getRepo("basil2style", new Callback<Repository>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Repository> call, Response<Repository> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Repository> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


And my model class is 
  
  package functionapps.retrofitdemo.AsyncHelper;

public class Repository {

    public  String name;

    public Repository(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }




}
```

```html
this is my interface and its calling class

public interface Github {

    @GET("/users/{user}")
    public void getRepo(@Path("user") String user, Callback<Repository> response);

}



public class GitHubService {
    private static String API_URL = "https://api.github.com";

    public static Github getService() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .build();
        Github github = retrofit.create(Github.class);

       return github;
    }
```

Comment: Please share stacktrace and share the version of retrofit as well ... like beta2 or 3 ....

Comment: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4

Comment: Please share stacktrace ..

Comment: stacktrace mns ?? my log i am beginner in android

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the  okHttp client dependency into your project also in retrofit 2 you need to encapsulate your api request with Call or an Observable using RxJava adapters
Here's how you can do it with call

So in your case the interface should be

```
 @GET("/users/{user}")
    public Call<Repository> getRepo(@Path("user") String user );
```

and calling code should be like

```
Call<Repository> call = apiService.getUser(username);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Repo>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Repo> response) {
     }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

With call you can also cancel an ongoing api call
You can read these tutorial for more info
https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en